# Can someone please help me update two dimensional array in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I see that my store is getting updated correctly but the react is not rendering the component. Please let me know how to update 2 dimensional array correctly so that react renders it.

**mainReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  displayList: [[1]],
  ruleGroup: [[{ field: "Theme", condition: "Equals", criteria: "Offers" }]],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
let obj = null;

switch(action.type){
 case DISPLAY_LIST_ADD_NEW_RULE:
      parentIndex = action.payload.parentIndex;
      obj = { ...state };
      obj.displayList[parentIndex].push(1);
      return obj;
 }
}
```

So, I have to push a value 1(in my case) to a specific location in a two dimensional array. Can someone please tell me how to do this correctly? Also would appreciate if you could add how to delete as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this

```
    case DISPLAY_LIST_ADD_NEW_RULE:
      return {
        ...state,
        displayList: state.displayList.map((list, index) => {
          return index === action.payload.parentIndex ? [...list, 1] : list
        }),
      }
```

Hard to say if anything else is going wrong. A link to a codesandbox or git repo could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There's more than what's given to assess what is really going on here...but maybe this helps

```
const initialState = {
  displayList: [[1]],
  ruleGroup: [[{ field: "Theme", condition: "Equals", criteria: "Offers" }]],
};

function myCustomFunction(index, arr){
// see stackoverflow link below
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
let obj = null;

switch(action.type){
 // this case type wasn't defined anywhere, made it a string'
 case 'DISPLAY_LIST_ADD_NEW_RULE':
      const parentIndex = action.payload.parentIndex;
      const newDisplayInsert = myCustomFunction(parentIndex, state.displayList)
      // see related stackoverflow article
      return {...state, displayList: newDisplayInsert };
 
 default: return state
}
}
```

I'd recommend having a custom action handle this outside the reducer

[How to update a value in 2D array in redux reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323901/how-to-update-a-value-in-2d-array-in-redux-reducer)